# Convert HEVC mkv to mp4 without transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video, conversion, h.265

I'm trying to remux h265 MKV to MP4 without transcoding.
My demo video is [tears-of-steel](https://www.libde265.org/hevc-bitstreams/tos-1720x720-cfg01.mkv).

I'm using the following command but I cannot play the resulting file

`ffmpeg -i tos-1720x720-cfg01.mkv -tag:v hvc1 -codec copy tos-1720x720-cfg01.mp4`

Command output:

```
ffmpeg -i tos-1720x720-cfg01.mkv -tag:v hvc1 -codec copy tos-1720x720-cfg01.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'tos-1720x720-cfg01.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
    creation_time   : 2014-03-18T13:19:29.000000Z
  Duration: 00:12:14.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1048 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1720x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 43:18, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
  Stream #0:2(hrv): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:3(cze): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:4(dan): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:5(ger): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:6(eng): Subtitle: subrip (default)
  Stream #0:7(spa): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:8(fre): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:9(gre): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:10(heb): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:11(hun): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:12(ind): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:13(ita): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:14(jpn): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:15(dut): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:16(nor): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:17(per): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:18(pol): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:19(por): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:20(rus): Subtitle: subrip
  Stream #0:21(chi): Subtitle: subrip
[mp4 @ 0x7fc32283b800] track 1: codec frame size is not set
Output #0, mp4, to 'tos-1720x720-cfg01.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv), 1720x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 43:18], q=2-31, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=N/frame=17620 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   94268kB time=00:12:14.00 bitrate=1052.1kbits/s speed=1.99e+03x    
video:53563kB audio:40142kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.601153%
```

Using ffprobe on the output file I get:

```
[extract_extradata @ 0x7fd9abc176c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[hevc @ 0x7fd9ac00b000] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[extract_extradata @ 0x7fd9abc176c0] No start code is found.
tos-1720x720-cfg01.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Trying to play with VLC anyway I can only hear the sound but not the video.

Here are codec informations
[image: codec infos]

Details:

```
Mac OS Big Sur: version 11.2.3 (20D91)
ffprobe version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)

ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
```

Comment: Show the complete log from your ffmpeg command.

Comment: @llogan I updated with the command output, nothing seems wrong at first sight.

Comment: What’s the tag for? Maybe it’s incorrect.

Comment: the tag set explicitly the video codec (afaik) ...anyway with or without nothing changes

Comment: Consider submitting a [bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/) (if there isn't one already). Make sure to use a version of ffmpeg from the current git master branch: see [homebrew](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS) or download it from [evermeet](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/). Provide the command and the complete log and a link to the input file.

Answer (score 0):

From https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265

Final Cut and Apple stuff compatibility

To make your file compatible with Apple "industry standard" H.265 you have to add the following argument -tag:v hvc1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1112933)